# Google Search Console does not recognize canonical links

Tags: html, hyperlink, canonical-link

I've read all questions about the "Duplicate without user-selected canonical" report in the Google Search Console, but could not find an answer for my problem.

Each and every page on my site partyflock.nl has a `link` with `rel=canonical`, nut still Google Search Console complains about more than 408K pages that have no user-selected canonical.

Take for example this page, of which Google Search Console says there is no user-selected canonical:

https://partyflock.nl/artist/132074:De-Bromeos

Does anyone have an idea what the reason for these compaints could be? I would be delighted to kanow the reason!

I've verified more than 10 pages about which Google Search Console complains, but each and everyone has a canonical link. I've put the HTML code through a parser and it's 'good' enough, at least the links should be recognized fine.